# How do I search one array for items from another array in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a `users` table that has the following data structure:

```
[{
    userID: 0,
    username: 'test0',
    petsForSale: [
        { type: 'fish' },
        { type: 'cats' }
    ],
    seekingPets: [
        { type: 'dogs' },
        { type: 'birds' }
    ]
},
{
    userID: 1,
    username: 'test1',
    petsForSale: [
        { type: 'guinea pigs' },
        { type: 'dogs' },
        { type: 'hamsters' }
    ],
    seekingPets: [
        { type: 'ferrets' }
    ]
}]
```

I'm trying to execute a `GET` that returns matched users based on `petsForSale` and `seekingPets`. For example, if a user is selling `dogs`, they will show up on the list of matched results for any user with `dogs` in `seekingPets`. I'm very close, here's my router code so far:

```
router.get('/:id/findmatches', function(req, res) {
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('users');
  var uid = req.params.id;

  //var seeking_pets = collection.find({ userID: uid }, { seekingPets: 1 });
  //var seeking_pets = collection.find({ userID: uid }, { seekingPets: { type: 1 }});
  var seeking_pets = [ 'dogs', 'birds' ]; // *Hard-coded is the only way I can get it to work

  collection.find({ petsForSale: { $elemMatch: { type: { $in: seeking_pets }}}}, function(e, docs) {
      res.json(docs);
  });
});
```

This code compiles and works just fine with `seeking_pets` hard-coded - visiting `/users/0/findmatches` returns user `test1` as expected. I'm stuck extracting the list of `seekingPets` from the `userID` in the request and searching through it in `collection.find`. The two commented lines are what I've tried without success. I've also tried converting the `collection` to an `array`.

Comment: Why you didn't query with this 2 conditions at once, using $and operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `find` is an async method, you must implement a callback in order to get the values returned from the database. Also notice that your hardcoded values are strings, but the seekingPets array is of objects.

Try this:

```
router.get('/:id/findmatches', function(req, res) {
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('users');
  var uid = req.params.id;

  collection.findOne({ userID: uid }, function(err, user)
      var seeking_pets = [].
      for (var i = 0; i < user.seekingPets.length; i++) {
        seeking_pets.push(user.seekingPets[i].type);
      }

      collection.find({ petsForSale: { $elemMatch: { type: { $in: seeking_pets }}}}, function(e, docs) {
          res.json(docs);
      });

  });
});
```

Notice that I use `findOne` in order to get an object instead of an array, and from this object I get the seekingPets array. Of course you can improve this code, eliminate some dispensable variables like `seeking_pets` and handle the database error if the id is not found.

Comment: Just tried this without success. Hard-coding `seeking_pets` inside `findOne` worked as before. Any other ideas?

Comment: I just noticed your userId is a number, are you sure that req.params.id is not a string?

Comment: Also check if findOne err is something other than undefined or null

Comment: So findOne `err` is `null` and I checked the type of `userID` and found no issues (even hard-coded userID to make sure). Same result as before. I did a `console.log(user.seekingPets[0].name)` as a test and was returned the correct name. I feel we're getting closer.

Comment: wow, just saw that your seekingPets is an array of objects. I'll update my answer to reflect ir

Comment: done, notice how your second find expects an array of strings, but the seekingPets was an array of objects, so it would never find. I'm not sure about object comparison on mongo, so I thought that the safest approach was to get all types and put it on another array, but you could make some tests

Comment: also, you said console.log(user.seekingPets[0].name) but on the use structure it is as type, so I used type because it is type on the question

Comment: Magic. Thanks so much!